# Is autocmd always called in a vimrc?

Tags: macos, vim

I have in my `.vimrc`:

```
fun! MySys()
    if has('win16') || has('win32') || has('win64')
        return "win"
    endif
endfun
```

And in my .gvimrc:

```
if MySys() == "win"
    autocmd GUIEnter * simalt ~ x " start maximized"
endif
```

For some reason, the autocmd is being called when I open macvim in a mac workstation. It shouldn't because I'm on a mac and the autocmd is inside a win if.

What problem can this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that you're doing a strange comparison.

The `MySys()` function will return `1` if you're on Windows and `0` if you're not.  You're then comparing `0` to "win", which (for reasons I don't really understand) produces a match.

How about changing to this:

```
fun! MySys()
    if has('win16') || has('win32') || has('win64')
        return "win"
    elseif has('mac') || has('maxunix')
        return "mac"
    elseif has("unix") || has("win32unix")
        " Unix or Cygwin (which acts like Unix)
        return "unix"
    else
        return "other"
    endif
endfun
```

(Untested)

Comment: The original comparison evaluated as true, I think, because in a comparison between a string and a number, Vim will always try to convert the string to a number.  E.g., 0=='win' is true, because str2nr('win')=0. On the other hand, 0=='3' will be false, since str2nr('3') equals 3.

Comment: Even using this approach, the line with the autocmd keeps getting evaluated. I've tried ':echo has('win32') in my vim and indeed it returns 0.

Comment: @Herbert Sitz: hum, so I should put "return "other"" as @AI says in the end of my function to avoid this comparisons? I going to try it.

Comment: @Somebody still uses you MS-DOS Either add `return "not win"` just before `endfunction` or replace `==` with `is`.

Comment: @Somebody:Yes, you need to return some text.  But are you sure you're reloading the changes, i.e, are you exiting Vim completely and restarting or 'sourcing' the vimrc after you change it?

Comment: @Herbert Sitz: Yes, I'm reloading the changes.

Comment: @Somebody:  If problem persists after incorporating above changes, then most likely problem seems like GUIEnter autocommand is getting issued somewhere else in your code.  Using 'autocmd GUIEnter' will not erase former autocommands setting functions to run upon GUIEnter, you'd need to do 'autocmd! GUIEnter' first for that. . .

Comment: @Herbert Sitz: I only call GUIenter in that section, in .gvimrc. The problem only happens in macvim, thats whats strange. Thanks for helping!